# Loading jQuery plugin using Systemjs

Tags: systemjs

I am trying to load a jQuery plugin on a JSPM/Systemjs setup. Am using a sample plugin called `vanillabox` to try it out. My `config.js` looks as below:

```
  meta: {
    "vanillabox": {
      "format": "global",
      "deps": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    }
  },
  map: {
    "vanillabox": "plugins/vanillabox/jquery.vanillabox-0.1.7.min",
    ....
  }
```

I am loading vanillabox in my module as follows -

```
define(function(require) {
    require("vanillabox");
})
```

The browser does not load the dependency as seen below -
[image: Chrome Network]

I am new to SystemJS and trying to figure what I am doing wrong here. Thanks for help here.

PS: I pre-installed jQuery using `jspm install jquery`

Answer (score 0):

The way to debug this is to look at the *normalized* SystemJS configuration that is created by inspecting `Object.keys(SystemJS.meta)`. You want to ensure that the meta entry for vanillabox matchest the full path to the file - `https://.../plugins/vanillabox/jquery.vanillabox-0.1.7.min.js`. Depending on how what you have doesn't match that it could then be due to the default extension or map configuration not being triggered correctly somehow.